# Реализация свойства Count коллекции Collection

Tags: c#, .net, коллекции

Делаю свою реализацию коллекции на основе массива.
Наследуюсь от шаблонного интерфейса Collection.

Проблемы с реализацией свойства Count. Я сделал так:

```
    public int Count
    {
        get
        {
            int counter = 0;
            while (array[counter] != null)
                counter++;
            return counter;
        }
    }
```

Мне же указали, что она является не очень правильной

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Для того, чтобы обратиться к существующей коллекции по индексу, нужно знать максимальное значение индекса. Иначе произойдёт исключение при выходе за границу коллекции.
2. Максимальный индекс коллекции вы можете спросить у самой коллекции. Это её свойство `.Count` (или `.Length`, если это массив). Ну и раз у вас есть длина, ничего не нужно вычислять.
3. Вы ухитрились реализовать операцию необычайно неэффективным способом: вы перебираете все элементы! Такой ужасный способ работает на сишных строках, потому что (а) в сишной строке гарантированно есть финальный нулевой элемент, и промежуточных нулевых элементов нет, и (б) другого, эффективного способа найти длину сишной строки нет. Но для высокоуровневых коллекций вы должны использовать быстрые методы.
4. Если в вашей реализации длина массива не обязательно равна длине коллекции, заведите поле `count`, содержащее реальную длину коллекции, и поддерживайте его в правильном состоянии. От коллекций ожидается, что опрос длины происходит за O(1) (то есть, скорость не зависит от числа элементов).

Comment: 2. У меня массив изначально создается на 10 элементов, если добавляется 11, то расширение в двое. Потому вариант с Length отпадает. 
4. У меня имеется свойство currentindex, которое изначально равно -1. При добавлении элемента увеличивается на единицу. Т.е я свойством Count должен возвращать currentindex + 1. Такая реализация подойдет? Или имеются варианты лучше?

Спасибо. Понял.

Comment: @TorSen так и делайте. При удалении только уменьшать не забывайте. Ну и это... перед написанием велосипедов не мешает ознакомиться с существующими решениями. Вот, например, [реализация `List<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/78a69d857716bc68.html).

Comment: Спасибо .Смотрел на mdsn реализацию Collection, там был только вариант на основе List, который не подошел.